# Referencing to different sibling nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

How would I achieve this in xsl? I have tried using it with `apply-templates` but I'm having no luck.

test.xml

```
<row>
    <table name="Person">
        <tuple>
            <val>BOB</val>
            <val>BILL</val>
        </tuple>
    </table>
    <table name="Age">
        <tuple>
            <val>18</val>
            <val>21</val>
        </tuple>
    </table>
</row>
```

Desired output

```
<row>
    <data>
        <name>BOB</name>
        <age>18</age>
    </data>
    <data>
        <name>BILL</name>
        <age>21</age>
    </data>
</row>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way this could be achieved is by using an `xsl:key` to look up the `val` elements based on their position

```
 <xsl:key name="values" match="val" use="count(preceding-sibling::val)" />
```

You would then iterate over the `val` elements in the first `table`

```
<xsl:for-each select="table[1]/tuple/val">
```

Then, you can get all the `val` elements that will make up the `data` elements using the key

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('values', position() - 1)" />
```

The only real messy bit is how you map a `name` attribute of "Person" to output an element of "name" instead.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="values" match="val" use="count(preceding-sibling::val)" />

    <xsl:template match="/row">
        <row>
            <xsl:for-each select="table[1]/tuple/val">
                <data>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('values', position() - 1)" />
                </data>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="val">
        <xsl:variable name="name">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../../@name = 'Person'">name</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="translate(../../@name, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" /></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="{$name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Apart from the messy `xsl:choose` this solution is also fairly generic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way of doing a destructuring bind with XSL;  I'd be interested to know if there is a native idiom for that.

Anyway:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/row">
  <row>
  <xsl:for-each select="table[@name='Person']/tuple/val">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <data>
      <name><xsl:value-of select="." /></name>
      <age><xsl:value-of select="../../../table[@name='Age']/tuple/val[position()=$i]" /></age>
    </data>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </row>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Admittedly not the prettiest XSL stylesheet out there, but it does the trick.

Of course, it is assumed that every name entry has a matching age entry here.  It would help a lot if your name and age entries were cross-referenced by id in the original XML document.